# No funciona la preview con Navigation Compose

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, navigation, jetpack-compose

Acabo de añadir la navegación a un proyecto que tengo hecho con Jetpack Compose. El caso es que tengo el navController seguido del NavHost en un fichero aparte, al que llamo desde la MainActivity. Al compilar e instalar, funciona correctamente. El problema es que la preview no funciona.
Mi código es este:

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = AppScreens.VistaPrincipal.route){
        composable(route = AppScreens.VistaPrincipal.route){
            VistaPrincipal(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Desde la MainActivity llamo a ese componente tanto en el Preview como en el setContent y no funciona. He probado, incluso, a meter ese contenido dentro del preview y me sigue sin mostrar.
¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

No te va a funcionar devido a que AppNavigation tiene a un NavHost dentro el cual no dara una vista previa. Para solucionarlo solo extrae el composable VistaPrincipal

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun myPreview() {
  VistaPrincipal(rememberNavController())
}
```